# First element inserted in a Map is always read as null

Tags: java, java-8

I have a Java 8 web application that reads a CSV file and maps its headers and values into a map. For some reason I don't know why the first element inserted into this map I never get to retrieve its value. I've already changed the CSV file colums order and the problem occurs the exactly same way.

When I debug my map I have it as follows:

[image]

As you can see I have the entry "Natureza" and its value is "RECEITA". That was the first element inserted into the map. But when I try to retrieve its value I always get null as an answer as you can see ahead:

[image]

Here's the method code that parses the CSV file into my entity:

```
@Transactional
public void processarArquivoCSV(final MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    if (file != null) {
        try (InputStream arquivo = file.getInputStream()) {
            final String[] fileAsStrArray = Constantes.PATTERN_QUEBRA_LINHA
                    .split(IOUtils.toString(arquivo, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            final String[] header = Constantes.PATTERN_VIRGULA.split(fileAsStrArray[0]);
            final List<Titulo> titulos = new ArrayList<>();
            final Collection<String> todosErros = new ArrayList<>();
            final FormaPagamento formaPagamentoImportacao = this.formaPagamentoService
                    .obterFormaPagamentoDesbloqueadaPorDescricaoAsEntity("IMPORTADO");
            final ClassificacaoFinanceira cfContaAzulReceita = this.classificacaoFinanceiraService
                    .findClassificacaoFinanceiraContaAzulPorNatureza(NaturezaFinanceiraEnum.RECEITA);
            final ClassificacaoFinanceira cfContaAzulDespesa = this.classificacaoFinanceiraService
                    .findClassificacaoFinanceiraContaAzulPorNatureza(NaturezaFinanceiraEnum.DESPESA);

            for (int i = 1; i < fileAsStrArray.length; i++) {
                final String[] linhaCSV = Constantes.PATTERN_VIRGULA.split(fileAsStrArray[i]);
                if (header.length != linhaCSV.length) {
                    todosErros.add(String.format(
                            "Registro %d inválido. Número de colunas diferente do número de informações. Número de colunas totalizando %d e número de informações totalizando %d.",
                            Integer.valueOf(i), Integer.valueOf(header.length), Integer.valueOf(linhaCSV.length)));
                    continue;
                }

                final Map<String, String> tituloMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
                for (int j = 0; j < header.length; j++) {
                    tituloMap.put(header[j], linhaCSV[j]);
                }

                final Titulo titulo = Titulo.builder().pisRetido(BigDecimal.ZERO).cofinsRetido(BigDecimal.ZERO)
                        .csllRetido(BigDecimal.ZERO).irrfRetido(BigDecimal.ZERO).inssRetido(BigDecimal.ZERO)
                        .issRetido(BigDecimal.ZERO).valorBase(BigDecimal.ZERO)
                        .formaPagamento(formaPagamentoImportacao).build();
                final Collection<String> erros = new ArrayList<>();
                final String situacao = tituloMap.get("Situacao");
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(situacao)) {
                    titulo.setSituacao(
                            (short) SituacaoFinanceiraEnum.valueOf(situacao).getValorSituacaoFinanceira());
                } else {
                    erros.add("Situação do título não pode ser vazia ou nula.");
                }

                final String natureza = tituloMap.get("Natureza").toUpperCase(Constantes.LOCALE_PT_BR);
                final NaturezaFinanceiraEnum naturezaEnum = NaturezaFinanceiraEnum.valueOf(natureza);
                final short naturezaAsShort = (short) naturezaEnum.getValorNaturezaFinanceira();
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(natureza)) {
                    titulo.setNatureza(naturezaAsShort);
                }

                final String nomeEstabelecimento = tituloMap.get("Estabelecimento");
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(nomeEstabelecimento)) {
                    final Optional<Estabelecimento> estabelecimentoOpt = this.estabelecimentoService
                            .findByDescricaoOuNomeFantasia(nomeEstabelecimento.trim());
                    if (estabelecimentoOpt.isPresent()) {
                        titulo.setEstabelecimento(estabelecimentoOpt.get());
                    } else {
                        erros.add("O estabelecimento informado é inexistente.");
                    }
                } else {
                    erros.add("O estabelecimento do título deve ser informado.");
                }

                final String vencimento = tituloMap.get("Data de vencimento");
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(vencimento)) {
                    try {
                        titulo.setVencimento(DateTimeUtil.DATE_FORMATTER_PT_BR.parse(vencimento, LocalDate::from));
                    } catch (DateTimeParseException | IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        erros.add(String.format(
                                "A data de vencimento do título é inválida. Data de vencimento informada: %s. Erro encontrado: %s.",
                                vencimento, e.getMessage()));
                    }
                } else {
                    erros.add("A data de vencimento do título não pode ser nula.");
                }

                final String competenciaAsString = tituloMap.get("Data de Competência");
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(competenciaAsString)) {
                    try {
                        final LocalDate competencia = DateTimeUtil.DATE_FORMATTER_PT_BR.parse(competenciaAsString,
                                LocalDate::from);
                        titulo.setCompetencia(competencia);
                        titulo.setEmissao(competencia);
                    } catch (DateTimeParseException | IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        erros.add(String.format(
                                "A data de competência do título é inválida. Data de competência informada: %s. Erro encontrado: %s.",
                                competenciaAsString, e.getMessage()));
                    }
                } else {
                    erros.add("A data de vencimento do título não pode ser nula.");
                }

                final String valor = tituloMap.get("Valor original");
                final boolean isReceita = NaturezaFinanceiraEnum.RECEITA == naturezaEnum;
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(valor)) {
                    final DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Constantes.LOCALE_PT_BR);
                    df.setParseBigDecimal(true);
                    try {
                        final BigDecimal valorAsBigDecimal = (BigDecimal) df.parseObject(valor);
                        titulo.setValor(valorAsBigDecimal);

                        final RateioFinanceiro rateio = RateioFinanceiro.builder().valor(valorAsBigDecimal).build();

                        final String nomeClassificacaoFinanceira = tituloMap.get("Categoria");
                        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(nomeClassificacaoFinanceira)) {
                            // TODO: Pesquisar os filhos do Conta Azul antes de criar.
                            rateio.setClassificacaoFinanceira(this.classificacaoFinanceiraService
                                    .findByDescricaoAndPaiContaAzul(nomeClassificacaoFinanceira.trim(),
                                            (isReceita ? cfContaAzulReceita : cfContaAzulDespesa).getGid())
                                    .map(cf -> cf)
                                    .orElseGet(() -> this.classificacaoFinanceiraService
                                            .save(ClassificacaoFinanceira.builder()
                                                    .paiId(isReceita ? cfContaAzulReceita : cfContaAzulDespesa)
                                                    .natureza(Short.valueOf(
                                                            (short) naturezaEnum.getValorNaturezaFinanceira()))
                                                    .codigo(nomeClassificacaoFinanceira)
                                                    .codigoAuxiliar(nomeClassificacaoFinanceira)
                                                    .descricao(nomeClassificacaoFinanceira)
                                                    .descricaoAuxiliar(nomeClassificacaoFinanceira).build())));
                        }

                        final String descricaoCentroCusto = tituloMap.get("Centro de custo");
                        if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(descricaoCentroCusto)) {
                            rateio.setCentroCusto(
                                    this.centroCustoService.findByDescricao(descricaoCentroCusto).map(cc -> cc)
                                            .orElseGet(() -> this.centroCustoService
                                                    .save(CentroCusto.builder().codigo(descricaoCentroCusto)
                                                            .descricao(descricaoCentroCusto).build())));
                        }

                        titulo.setDocumentoRateado(DocumentoRateado.builder().valor(valorAsBigDecimal)
                                .rateiosFinanceiros(CollectionUtil.buildSingletonModifiableList(rateio)).build());
                    } catch (final ParseException e) {
                        erros.add(String.format(
                                "O valor do título é inválido. Valor informado: %s. Erro encontrado: %s.", valor,
                                e.getMessage()));
                    }
                } else {
                    erros.add("O valor do título não pode ser nulo ou vazio.");
                }

                final String numero = tituloMap.get("Descrição");
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(numero)) {
                    if (numero.length() > 30) {
                        erros.add("O número do título não pode conter mais do que trinta caracteres.");
                    } else {
                        titulo.setNumero(numero);
                        titulo.setDocumentoVinculado("ContaAzul-" + numero);
                    }
                } else {
                    erros.add("O número do título não pode ser nulo ou vazio.");
                }

                final String numeroDocumento = tituloMap.get("CNPJ / CPF");
                final String nomeCliente = tituloMap.get("Cliente");
                final String numeroDocumentoParseado = Constantes.PATTERN_ONLY_DIGITS.matcher(numeroDocumento)
                        .replaceAll(StringUtils.EMPTY);
                if (StringUtils.isBlank(numeroDocumento) && StringUtils.isBlank(nomeCliente)) {
                    erros.add("Deve ser informado pelo menos o nome ou o documento do cliente.");
                } else if (nomeCliente.length() > 150) {
                    erros.add("Nome do cliente não deve conter mais do que 150 caracteres.");
                } else if (numeroDocumentoParseado.length() > 14) {
                    erros.add("Número do documento do cliente não deve conter mais do que 14 caracteres.");
                } else if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(numeroDocumentoParseado)) {
                    if (!VitaiUtil.isCNPJValido(numeroDocumentoParseado)
                            && !VitaiUtil.isCPFValido(numeroDocumentoParseado)) {
                        erros.add("O número do documento do cliente não é válido como CNPJ ou como CPF.");
                    } else {
                        final Optional<Pessoa> pessoa = this.pessoaService
                                .findByNumeroDocumento(numeroDocumentoParseado);
                        if (pessoa.isPresent()) {
                            titulo.setPessoa(pessoa.get());
                        } else if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(nomeCliente)) {
                            final Optional<Pessoa> pessoaBackup = this.pessoaService
                                    .findByNomeOuNomeFantasia(nomeCliente);
                            if (pessoaBackup.isPresent()) {
                                titulo.setPessoa(pessoaBackup.get());
                            } else {
                                titulo.setPessoa(this.pessoaService.save(Pessoa.builder().nome(nomeCliente)
                                        .nomeFantasia(nomeCliente).numeroDocumento(numeroDocumento)
                                        .naturezaPessoa(Short.valueOf(naturezaAsShort)).bloqueado(false).build()));
                            }
                        } else {
                            erros.add(
                                    "Pessoa não encontrada e falta o nome do cliente para poder persistí-lo na base.");
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    final Optional<Pessoa> pessoaBackup = this.pessoaService.findByNomeOuNomeFantasia(nomeCliente);
                    if (pessoaBackup.isPresent()) {
                        titulo.setPessoa(pessoaBackup.get());
                    } else {
                        erros.add(
                                "Pessoa não encontrada e falta o número do documento do cliente para poder persistí-lo na base.");
                    }
                }

                final String valorBaixado = tituloMap.get(isReceita ? "Valor recebido" : "Valor pago");
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(valorBaixado)) {
                    final DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Constantes.LOCALE_PT_BR);
                    df.setParseBigDecimal(true);

                    try {
                        titulo.setValorBaixado((BigDecimal) df.parseObject(valorBaixado));
                    } catch (final ParseException e) {
                        erros.add(String.format(
                                "O valor baixado do título é inválido. Valor baixado informado: %s. Erro encontrado: %s.",
                                valor, e.getMessage()));
                    }
                } else {
                    erros.add("O valor baixado do título não pode ser nulo ou vazio.");
                }

                final String juros = tituloMap.get("Juros/Multa");
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(juros)) {
                    final DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Constantes.LOCALE_PT_BR);
                    df.setParseBigDecimal(true);

                    try {
                        titulo.setJuros((BigDecimal) df.parseObject(juros));
                    } catch (final ParseException e) {
                        erros.add(String.format(
                                "O valor do juros/multa do título é inválido. Valor baixado informado: %s. Erro encontrado: %s.",
                                valor, e.getMessage()));
                    }
                } else {
                    erros.add("O valor do juros/multa do título não pode ser nulo ou vazio.");
                }

                final String desconto = tituloMap.get("Descontos/Taxas");
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(desconto)) {
                    final DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Constantes.LOCALE_PT_BR);
                    df.setParseBigDecimal(true);

                    try {
                        titulo.setJuros((BigDecimal) df.parseObject(desconto));
                    } catch (final ParseException e) {
                        erros.add(String.format(
                                "O valor do desconto do título é inválido. Valor baixado informado: %s. Erro encontrado: %s.",
                                valor, e.getMessage()));
                    }
                } else {
                    erros.add("O valor do desconto do título não pode ser nulo ou vazio.");
                }

                final String conta = tituloMap.get("Conta");
                if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(conta)) {
                    this.contaService.findByCodigoOuNome(conta).ifPresent(titulo::setConta);
                }

                final String observacao = tituloMap.get("Observações");
                if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(observacao)) {
                    titulo.setObservacao(observacao);
                }

                titulo.setHistorico("Título criado pela importação de títulos Conta Azul.");

                if (!erros.isEmpty()) {
                    todosErros.add(String.format(
                            "Falha ao mapear registro %d do arquivo CSV para título. Registro não atende as especificações. ERRO(S):%n%s",
                            Integer.valueOf(i), String.join(Constantes.QUEBRA_LINHA_STR, erros)));
                } else {
                    titulos.add(titulo);
                }
            }

            if (!titulos.isEmpty()) {
                this.saveAll(titulos);
            }

            if (!todosErros.isEmpty()) {
                final String todosErrosAsStr = String.join(Constantes.QUEBRA_LINHA_STR, todosErros);
                TituloService.log.error(todosErrosAsStr);
                throw new RuntimeException(todosErrosAsStr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a clue what I might be doing wrong in this first insertion into the map?

**EDIT:**

After Holger comments I edited my solution and despite not solving my problem it led the application to be much faster. Here's the edited code:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream()))) {
    final List<Titulo> titulos = new ArrayList<>();
    final Collection<String> todosErros = new ArrayList<>();
    final String[] header = Constantes.PATTERN_VIRGULA.split(reader.readLine());
    String linhaCSV = StringUtils.EMPTY;
    final FormaPagamento formaPagamentoImportacao = this.formaPagamentoService
            .obterFormaPagamentoDesbloqueadaPorDescricaoAsEntity("IMPORTADO");
    final ClassificacaoFinanceira cfContaAzulReceita = this.classificacaoFinanceiraService
            .findClassificacaoFinanceiraContaAzulPorNatureza(NaturezaFinanceiraEnum.RECEITA);
    final ClassificacaoFinanceira cfContaAzulDespesa = this.classificacaoFinanceiraService
            .findClassificacaoFinanceiraContaAzulPorNatureza(NaturezaFinanceiraEnum.DESPESA);
    int i = 0;

    while ((linhaCSV = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        final String[] linhaCSVParseada = Constantes.PATTERN_VIRGULA.split(linhaCSV);
        if (header.length != linhaCSVParseada.length) {
            todosErros.add(String.format(
                    "Registro %d inválido. Número de colunas diferente do número de informações. Número de colunas totalizando %d e número de informações totalizando %d.",
                    Integer.valueOf(i), Integer.valueOf(header.length),
                    Integer.valueOf(linhaCSVParseada.length)));
            continue;
        }

        final Map<String, String> tituloMap = new HashMap<>(header.length);
        for (int j = 0; j < header.length; j++) {
            tituloMap.put(header[j], linhaCSVParseada[j]);
        }
    // The rest is the same as the first code provided...
    }
}
```

Comment: May be, in later iteration, you read the same key again whose value is `null`? Can you post the data ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but no, I do not read the value later again, the print screen I provided is the one and only time I read that column. And if I reorder the columns in the CSV file the problem still occurs with the new first inserted column.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. You're using `ConcurrentHashMap`, it cannot accept `null` keys or values. It would've failed with NPE. You need to add some print statements (debug) to see if you're reading the file incorrectly

Comment: The problem occurs with LinkedHashMap, HashMap or ConcurrentHashMap. I tried all these three implementations and the problem is still the same. And as you can see in my first print screen the value is there and it is not null. I know for a fact that the problem is not in how I read the CSV file because I already switched the CSV file first column to be read four or five times. The problem is always with the first element inserted into the map regardless of the CSV file column order.

Comment: My guess is that there's a non-printing control character at the start of each line - eg, it's a LF/CR file but your IDE is not showing the CR.  The moral is : Don't trust solely what you see, but verify - eg, by logging `header[j].length()` as you do the `put`, and validate that it is 8 for "Natureza".

Comment: I guess, `Constantes.PATTERN_QUEBRA_LINHA` is the problem. Btw, this code is very inefficient, first reading the entire file into the memory as a giant string, then splitting it into a giant array of line strings (effectively having the file in memory two times), before iterating over the array and splitting each line further. When you simply use a `BufferedReader` and iterate using `readLine()`, only the current line needs to be in memory. Or you use `Scanner`, which even allows to iterate over the cells without the need to materialize the lines as strings. Both also fix the line break issue.

Comment: @racraman, I'll check what you mentioned. But if this is the problem, how would you solve it?

Comment: @Holger, `Constantes.PATTERN_QUEBRA_LINHA` is just a Pattern compiled with a line break `\n`. About the code, it was written this way because I can't assume the CSV file column order, it may come with multiple different orders. This way I have to create the map containing the header as a key and the CSV value as the map value. What would you suggest now that you know it?

Comment: Let’s see what it is first :).  Possible solutions could be to substring(1) to chop it off, or do a replaceall to replace it with empty string “” - but ideally doing what @Holger says about a line-at-a-time might fix it, as Java is pretty good with different line formats.

Comment: If you’re on Linux, you could run the command `od -xc filename | head -1` to explicitly output the first few bytes of the file - and then edit the question to add that output.

Comment: @racraman, your first answer was the right one. I had a UTF-8 file with BOM and that was the issue. If you provide an answer I'll be more than happy to accept it.

Comment: @Holger your comment were very important to, the solution is much faster now. I'll edit the question and show the edits I made in the code.

Comment: The reason I referred to that pattern was similar to [racraman’s suspicion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64584421/?noredirect=1#comment114209395_64584421) (we commented almost at the same time). In the end, it was very close, BOM instead of line breaks…

Comment: But BOM only happens in the first char of the whole file. The line break pattern was used to read each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file starts with non-printable character(s), which becomes part of the key value for the first column only - which means both that the IDE isn’t displaying the complete key, and searching the map using only printable characters would not find an entry.